# How to make all scopes mandatory in google oauth 2.0?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I have this app. Verification completed. The fact that the picture is a user authorization window on my site (giving rights to use certain scope) And why some of them can be turned off. How to make it so that the user can not choose what to give and what not. I need all scope.

I read many docs, but can't find the right decision.

```php
    require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/class/config.php');
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($gsuite["clientName"]);
    $client->setClientId($gsuite["clientId"]);
    $client->setClientSecret($gsuite["clientSecret"]);
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setRedirectUri($gsuite['dev_redirect']);
    $client->setPrompt('select_account');
    $client->setScopes($gsuite['scopes']);
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    exit;
```

I want to see this screen in my app - https://yadi.sk/i/FBcCufBTXJRgVA
Now i see this - https://yadi.sk/i/9Pb_TtI_BfXucg

Comment: This is probably decided by Google. They respect the users' right to reject on something. Maybe you can keep denying all services and constantly, repeatedly asking the user until all scopes granted. Probably showing some message `"We cannot provide the services without permission granted"`. You are probably doing it wrong if you are forcing the user to do something.

Comment: @Илья Державин Did you find any solution for this? I am having the same issue. Thanks!